# How can I uninstall unwanted OS, but keep Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, retropie

So, I'm trying to find a good PSX emulator, and I eventually install RetroPie to dual boot alongside Raspbian. Which was (in my case) a very bad decision. Now I cannot boot either of them due  to some form of error (likely to be that my RPI isn't receiving enough power), and I'm trying to uninstall RetroPie from my PINN v3.2.1 installer (Very much like NOOBS, but with more options). While in a normal scenario I'd just reinstall PINN, I do happen to have a project on Raspbian that I don't exactly feel like starting over at the moment. I'm thinking of manually removing RetroPie from my SD card, though some other suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: How did you  "install RetroPie to dual boot alongside Raspbian"? What have you tried?

Comment: If the problem is that the device is not receiving enough power (which I doubt, but you don't say why you think that, so assuming you have a good reason) then removing an OS from the card isn't going to help.